# How give MS word like interface to user to expand or contract display object's like canvas, images

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

How to give a ms word like interface to a user so that he can enlarge and contract the display objects like Images, canvas, Hrules etc. at runtime in an web application?

Answer (score 0):

google for `'richedit js'`. For example, [JS-RichEdit](http://www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/richedit/)